# ReferenceManyFields (One to Many Relationship)

Tags: graphql, react-admin, hasura

I am working on a project where I have to create one to many relationships which will get all the list of records referenced by id in another table and I have to display all the selected data in the multi-select field `(selectArrayInput)`. Please help me out in this, if you help with an example that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

```
Example:
district
id    name
1     A
2     B
3     C

block
id    district_id    name
1     1              ABC
2     1              XYZ
3     2              DEF
```

I am using `https://github.com/Steams/ra-data-hasura-graphql` ***hasura-graphql dataprovider*** for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely looking for "nested object queries" (see: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/nested-object-queries.html#nested-object-queries)

An example...

```
query MyQuery {
  district(where: {id: {_eq: 1}}) {
    id
    name
    blocks {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "district": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "blocks": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ABC"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "XYZ"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or...

```
query MyQuery2 {
  block(where: {district: {name: {_eq: "A"}}}) {
    id
    name
    district {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "block": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ABC",
        "district": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "XYZ",
        "district": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Setting up the tables this way...

blocks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

districts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Aside: I recommend using plural table names as they are more standard, "districts" and "blocks"